# How to get user info on a static page?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm hosting a static page/site on GCP App Engine (written in standard js/html/css), on a company domain ;

I know in localhost testing I can't get the user info in any way (which is fine, I'll hardcode dummy data).

But after using gcloud app deploy and running it on the engine, is there a way to obtain user info somehow? Name, email etc. Ideally just through the app somehow - or even by calling a google cloud function or something.

Nb. I have activated IAP so when hosted, the user does go through google auth on this site (all domain users are allowed in).

Comment: You can't do this from a static page because you don't have any opportunity to do any processing.  The static page just returns existing data and doesn't really hit your app.

Comment: Is there a way to serve a landing page with additional info through backend then do the rest as frontend/static?

Answer (score 1):

If you have turned on IAP, then to get the information you want, you have to look at the headers

From [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/identity-howto)

....IAP also passes the user's identity to your backend service in the following HTTP headers.

*`X-Goog-Authenticated-User-Email`* :  The user's email address

*`X-Goog-Authenticated-User-Id`* : A persistent, unique identifier for the user

**Tip:** Do a dump of the headers in your code to see what else you might find useful.

Comment: If I'm serving static pages I don't have a response object to work with / get the headers from - do I? Because it's all client side?